# Image does not show up in treeview tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, image, treeview, customtkinter

Can you please help me to solve the issue with code where it does not show images in treeview saved in a temporary directory retrieved from a mysql database..
Please look onto this..

```
            def get_imgs():
                global td
                global img_ref
                img_ref = []
                td = tempfile.mkdtemp()
                cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Candidates")
                r = cur.fetchall()
                for i in r:
                    b_dt = i[1]
                    img_dt = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b_dt))
                    img_dt.save(td+'/'+str(i[0])+'.png')
                    img_ref.append(img_dt)


            def insert_val():
                get_imgs()
                count=0
                cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Candidates")
                data = cur.fetchall()
                for record in data:
                     path = td+'/'+str(record[0])+'.png'
                    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
                    can_table.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, open=True, text='',  image=img, values=(record[0]))
                    count += 1

treestyle = ttk.Style()
            treestyle.theme_use('default')
            treestyle.configure("Treeview", background=bg_color, foreground=text_color, fieldbackground=bg_color,
                                borderwidth=0, font=('Koulen', 26), rowheight=80)
            treestyle.configure('Treeview.Heading', font=('Koulen', 22), foreground='white',
                                fieldbackground=bg_color, background=bg_color)
            treestyle.map('Treeview', background=[('selected', bg_color)],
                          foreground=[('selected', selected_color)])

            can_table = ttk.Treeview(fr, selectmode='browse', height=5)
            can_table.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

            can_table['columns'] = ("StudentName")
            can_table['show'] = ('tree headings')

            can_table.column("#0", anchor=CENTER, width=200)
            can_table.column("StudentName", anchor=CENTER, width=400)

            can_table.heading('#0', text='#')
            can_table.heading('StudentName', text='Student Name')

            can_table.tag_configure('oddrow', background='#161717')
            can_table.tag_configure('oddrow', background='#393C3C')
```

I basically tried to directly convert blob data into image and insert in treeview but that did not give good result either!

The image used to appear if its a single row but not for multiple images and that does not happen now!

I have mainly used custom tkinter for gui and appearance..

Comment: it would help if you add all imported libraries

Comment: import tempfile,
import shutil,
from customtkinter import *,
from tkinter import ttk,
import tkinter as tk,
from PIL import Image, ImageTk,
from CTkMessagebox import CTkMessagebox,
from customtkinter import filedialog,
import atexit,
import mysql.connector,
import io.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was a pretty small and silly mistake which i hadn't noticed!
The reference of the previous image in the range were garbage collected resulting to not show any image in treeview!

So I just referenced the images in the get_imgs() and saved it in a list which solved the problem..

Thank You